# Using $.ajax to get more values from php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get more values from just one php file with ajax.

My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "phpfile.php",
    success: function (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6) {
        $("#lga").html('<img src="' + value1 + '" alt="image" width="115" height="115"></src>');
        $("#lg").text(value2);
        $("#lgi").text(value3);
        $("#lgv").text(value4);
        $("#lgc").text(value5);
        $("#lt").text(value6);
    }
});
```

In the php I have 6 `echo`:

```
<?php
    $game = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
    $lastwinner = fetchinfo("userid","games","id",$game-1); 
    $winneravatar = fetchinfo("avatar","users","steamid",$lastwinner); 
    $chance = fetchinfo("percent","games","id",$game-1); 
    $items = fetchinfo("itemsnum","games","id",$game-1); 
    $ticket = fetchinfo("winticket","games","id",$game-1); 
    $value = round(fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$game-1),2); 
    $winnername = fetchinfo("winner","games","id",$game-1); 
    echo $winneravatar; 
    echo $game-1; 
    echo $items; 
    echo $value; 
    echo $chance; 
    echo round($ticket*100,7); 
    echo $winnername; 
?>
```

Comment: ... and then? Please provide more information about your actual php code and your desired results.

Comment: The function gets only the first value correctly. I am trying to take more values from just one php, instead of having 6 php files.

Comment: Please show your php code

Comment: don't put code in comments, edit your original post. it's nearly impossible to read it in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you pass array with ajax?
Like make an array in php code, and pass it in encoding form, eg.

```
echo json_encode($arrResult);
```

than in html form again parse it with `parseJSON()`.

eg. of ajax call for your reference

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpfile.php",
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            //alert(msg);
            msg = $.trim( msg );
            if(msg != '[]'){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

                $("#lga").html('');
                $("#lg").text(obj.value2);
                $("#lgi").text(obj.value3);
                $("#lgv").text(obj.value4);
                $("#lgc").text(obj.value5);
                $("#lt").text(obj.value6);
        }// if 

 });
```

in phpfile.php, your array should be

```
$returnArray[value2] = 'abc';
$returnArray[value3] = '234';
$returnArray[value4] = 'xyz';
$returnArray[value5] = 'pqr';
$returnArray[value6] = '987';

echo json_encode($returnArray);
```